# Check for two or more duplicates in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an android application for my school. We are assigned a Roll Number. I want to store students in firebase while making sure that no two student have the same roll number and Email. I'm storing them in a fashion similar to:

```
{
  "Users": {
    "Uid":{
      "data":{
        "Name": "",
        "RollNumber: "",
        "Email": "",
        "Phone": "",
        "Other Fields": ""
      },
      "otherData": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And maybe later extend to make certain combinations unique like no two students can have same combination of phone and date and birth(Just an example).

Comment: I would recommend you make RollNumber the UID of the user, because that makes it possible to enforce your rules via firebase security, otherwise its impossible and you would be relying on a client-side query (unsecure) or would have to setup CloudFunctions or AppEngine/Server to do the check. Also a query would be very inconvenient with your current structure because you cannot query 2 layers deep, so you would have to download the entire users node, every time (which for a school might be passable)

Comment: But I also want to make Phone no. and Uid as Unique. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Well in that cause, I would just unnest the data class so you can query either RollNumber or Email, and if one isn't unique, then check if the other is. You'll have to rely on using queries because the structure won't allow for firebase security to check, unless you change it/add additional nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, i recomand you implementing [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and [Google Signin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin). In this way, you'll be sure that the email is unique.

To verify the `Roll Number` for unicity, use the `Roll Number` in stead of `uid` and then just use `exists()` method on the reference. If there are too many users in your project, i recomand you create a new section named, `rollNumbers` and make the check only on this new sections. This means that you will not need to download the entire  user node. You'll only need download the `rollNumbers` node which is significant smaller.

In the same way you can achieve this for other fields.

Hope it helps.